# I can't move Apps to My SD card, the button isn't there

Tags: settings, internal-storage, sd-card, insufficient-memory, internal-sd

I need to move some or any apps to my micro SD card, because I am all out of space, but there isn't a "move to SD card " option. It's not just grayed out, it's gone. 
The SD card is formatted as internal storage, and It does seem to be connected to the phone properly. I even tried to migrate the data over several times but with no results. 
I tried linked2DS but I keep getting error messages saying "Linked2SD could not gain root access" but I don't know how to give it access? If I even have it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Lucky Patcher as move to sd card. start lucky patcher press on app and move to external card.